# Calendardatepicker dateformat

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is it possible to set dateformat in Calendardatepicker style/template?

```
  <Style x:Name="CalendarDatePicker" TargetType="CalendarDatePicker">

    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="DateFormat" Value="{}{day.integer}‎.‎{month.integer}‎.{year.full}" />

</Style>
```

I tried to do it as above but it does not work.

Comment: This should work. Can you confirm that the other properties are working on your CalendarDatePicker, like the Green Foreground?
Here is a link to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker

Comment: Yes other are working but dateformat not.

Comment: I am installing UWP now, if someone doesn't help you in meantime, I'll look at this.

Comment: I did a further investigation. It does not work even if I add it as a style from C#. It works directly from the control though. I don't know why is this happening, sorry. If I have more time later, I'll look at it again. In a meantime, if you find something, please post it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time. As soon as I find something, I will write the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't why CalendarDatePicker is designed in this way, DateFormat is only accepted if it's "ReadLocalValue" is true.
That mean the following two changes are valid:

```
<CalendarDatePicker x:Name="myCalendarDatePicker"
                    DateFormat = "{}{dayofweek.full}‎, ‎{month.full}‎ ‎{day.integer}‎, ‎{year.full}"/>
```

or

```
myCalendarDatePicker.DateFormat = "{dayofweek.full}‎, ‎{month.full}‎ ‎{day.integer}‎, ‎{year.full}";
```

So It doesn't work for your example. You can workaround the problem by creating a nested dummy CalendarDatePicker, but I don't suggest you to do it.

```
  <Style x:Key="CalendarDatePicker" TargetType="CalendarDatePicker">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="DateFormat" Value="{}{day.integer}‎.‎{month.integer}‎.{year.full}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDatePicker">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <CalendarDatePicker DateFormat="{TemplateBinding DateFormat}"
                                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```